# Is there a system Exception to throw when calling a function that wasn't meant to be called?

Tags: c#, exception

Let's put that I have an mutable object that has a function that mutates it, and that function should not be called under certain circumstances. How should I react to code calling a function under those circumstances?

For example:

- **Object**: Combat
- **Function**: PlayRound()
- **Circumstance**: The Combat has already a Winner
- **Consecuence**: Combat would end in an inconsistent state

I can think of two ways of acting, neither of which find suficient:

1. **Return a magic value**, `null` for example. This has the problem that it does not follow the Fail Faster ideology, and keeps the program in an invalid state.
2. **Throw an exception**. This is the one that I find more suitable, but I'd like to avoid creating a new `Exception` if it already exists one that fulfills that role.

For the second case, I could throw something like [`ArgumentInvalidException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.invalidargumentexception.aspx)
but I can't find the equivalent for this case.

**There is an equivalent existing Exception for this scenario?**

Note: Let's assume that the function is documented, and it says explicitly that the function should never be called under those circumstances. Still I think it should fail hard if the developer fails to read the documentation =)

Comment: [InvalidOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: That answers it perfectly!

Comment: You shouldnt be throwing exception at all - exception are for "wait, wha... how did you do this?" and not for "yeah, i know, not now..." Not sure if Fail-Fast is encouraging you to use exceptions, but i doubt it...

Comment: @splite `InvalidOperationException` is designed specifically for this purpose alone. If not exception, then what do you suggest?

Comment: @splite I disagree. "The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state" sounds pretty appropriate for this circumstance. What would you do instead?

Comment: Agreed, InvalidOperationException fits the most. MSDN: "The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state."

Comment: @spite No matter why the developer called `PlayRound()`, if it did when the combat already ended, s/he assumes that a round is gonna be played, so his code will go unpredictable ways unless stopped. That is another good reason to use `Exceptions`.

Comment: Have no idea what is Mestre doing, but why he have `combat` object still around when he already have winner?

Comment: Well, you got me :D Never mind, in this case, InvalidOperation is good solution :)

Comment: @GuillermoMestre this is something that should be unit-tested out. I would not try to program around programmers with exceptions. This kind of thing is easily caught by a good unit test and doesn't require bloating the application handling exceptions that only poor programming would cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define an application exception specific to that.  But you could use InvalidOperationException here sanely.